# Command to create ssh config file using git bash(windows)?

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys, git-bash

I could only find details about configuring the config file, but i could no where find how to create a config file manually. I have generated rsa key, which is under .ssh folder but i couldn't find the config file being created there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simply create it by yourself:

```
touch ~/.ssh/config
```

or go to `.ssh` directory and do only:

```
touch config
```

And then fill it with data.

Comment: @NickPerkins it is, but using git bash